# nonisomorphic graph drawings

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I am aware that isomorphic graphs must have the same number of vertices and same number of degrees on each point. But how many graphs are there to it? (Help is much appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

What the question desires you to do is to draw all ***different*** graphs on $5$ and $6$ vertices. The purpose is to avid situations where you might draw, say two triangles and just name the vertices differently and claim they are different. So by "draw all non-isomorphic graphs" it is meant for you to draw all graphs that are different under isomorphism.

You start by drawing $5$(or $6$) vertices and see how many ***different*** graphs you can draw using one edge. Then two edges. And then continue in this fashion making sure you do not draw two isomorphic graphs.There are too many to be drawn here.

But the truth is you will always miss one or two. I am not a fan of this sort of questions so I'm going to give you these two references to help you out. They are a list of all small different graphs up to isomorphism.

- http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html (*scroll down*)
- http://gfredericks.com/sandbox/graphs/browse?order=6&regular=true

Hope I helped.

Comment: You can try to use some software for drawing them, this is always helpful (see for instance the "sage" code in the question http://ask.sagemath.org/question/3473/nice-display-of-a-list-of-matrices )